# How to compute the volume of the solid bounded by the graph $z=x^{2}+y$, the rectangle $R=[0,1]\times [1,2]$ and the "vertical sides" of $R$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

Compute the volume of the solid bounded by the graph $z=x^{2}+y$, the rectangle $R=[0,1]\times [1,2]$ and the "vertical sides" of $R$.

**Solution:**

I know that $z=x^{2}+y$ is a parabolic cylinder, but I don't know how to draw that rectangle $R$ in 3D.

Some ideas, suggestions,...?

Answer (score 1):

When the region $R$ is bounded by curves it's nice to have a graph of it so you can tell what the bounds will be. But even then you don't need a 3D graph, it's a region in the $xy$ plane.

But when the region is a rectangle, as in this case, it's even easier. The sides of the rectangle are your bounds. No need to graph anything, Just evaluate

$$\int_1^2 \int_0^1 x^2+y \, dx\,dy
= \int_1^2 1/3+y\,dy
=11/6
$$

If you do want to visualize the graph, just picture that portion of the quadriceps surface over the rectangle in question.